# What is the best way to access css and js from drupal 8 theme

Tags: 8, theming

I am integrating angular 2 in a drupal 8 theme. Angular 2 needs to access multiple CSS and js files for the components.

If I include it using the libraries it gets concatenated and gets exported into files directory. I need concatenation for other resources. Is their a way to avoid concatenation for just one library alone.

The solution I took was to hardcode path to assets. Like /themes/themename/app/main.js etc...

Is this okay? Will it work in multi site as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. Custom module

Follow the examples module.

2. Header attributes

Via the module file

```
function module_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $xuacompatible = [
    '#tag' => 'base',
    '#attributes' => [
      'href' => '/my-will',
    ],
  ];

  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    $xuacompatible,
    'x-ua-compatible',
  ];

  $variables['html_attributes']['data-critters-container'] = "";
}
```

3. Include js via module hook.

I want to keep it on a specific page

```
function module_js_alter(&$javascript,) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  if ($current_path === '/node/4') {
    $javascript = [];

    $polyfill = Drupal::service('extension.list.module')
        ->getPath('will_exporter') . '/docwills/browser/polyfills.js';

    $javascript[$polyfill] = [
      'weight' => 100,
      'minified' => FALSE,
      'group' => 'interlated',
      'type' => 'file',
      'data' => $polyfill,
      'version' => '1.0.1',
      'cache' => TRUE,
      'preprocess' => FALSE,
      'attributes' => ['type' => 'module'],
      'licence' => [
        'name' => 'custom',
        'url' => 'https://www.interlated.com.au',
        'gpl-compatible' => FALSE,
      ],
      'scope' => 'footer',
    ];

    $angular_main = Drupal::service('extension.list.module')
        ->getPath('will_exporter') . '/docwills/browser/main.js';

    $javascript[$angular_main] = [
      'weight' => 100,
      'minified' => FALSE,
      'group' => 'interlated',
      'type' => 'file',
      'data' => $angular_main,
      'version' => '1.0.1',
      'cache' => TRUE,
      'preprocess' => FALSE,
      'attributes' => ['type' => 'module'],
      'licence' => [
        'name' => 'custom',
        'url' => 'https://www.interlated.com.au',
        'gpl-compatible' => FALSE,
      ],
      'scope' => 'footer',
    ];
  }
}
```

4. Include css via module.libaries.yml

   module:
   css:
   theme:
   docwills/browser/styles.css: { }
5. Create a block for the html element. Use the block example from the examples module

In the past I've attached the js files here. Link the inclusion of the files to the presence of the block.

```
/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "will_exporter",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Will Exporter"),
 *   category = @Translation("Interlated"),
 * )
 */
class AngularAppBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'app-root',
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'module/module',
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

6. Change the build destination in the angular app to the module location

Configure in *angular.json*

"outputPath": "../../web/modules/custom/module/exporter",

All the paths above point here

7. No output hashing in the package.json build script

If you keep this, you need to change the main.js and polyfills.js file names every time you build

```
"prod": "ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=none --base-href=./wills",
```

8. Run the "prod" script

   npm run prod

rebuild caches. Repeat until the javascript console shows no errors.